# AngularJS - что выдает $location.path()?

Tags: angularjs

Хочу узнать, что выдает $location.path() и почему рушиться Angular изза него. 
Что не так в коде?. В чем может быть причина?

Заранее спасибо!

```
   (function() {

angular.module('lostfound.common', []).controller('dateYear', function ($scope) {
        $scope.date = new Date();
    });
angular.module('lostfound.pathlocation', []).controller('locationPath', function ($scope) {
        $scope.lpath = $location.path();
    });
    //ROUTING
    var logApp = angular.module('lostfound.routing', ["ngRoute"]).config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl : "pages/home.html",
            })
            .when("/about_us", {
                templateUrl : "pages/about_us.html",
            })
            .when("/lost", {
                templateUrl : "pages/lost.html",
            })
            .when("/found", {
                templateUrl : "pages/found.html",
            })
            .when("/contact_us", {
                templateUrl : "pages/contact_us.html",
            })
            .when("/register", {
                templateUrl : "pages/register.html",
            })
            .when("/login", {
                templateUrl : "pages/popup/login.html",
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/"
            });

    });
    //gather modules
    angular.module('lostfound', ['lostfound.common','lostfound.pathlocation','lostfound.routing']);
})();
```

Comment: попробуй `$location.path() == '/'`. А еще лучше - просто посмотри. что тебе возвращает _$location.path()_ на главное странице

Comment: если использовать $location.path() == '/', то нигде не выводится нужный блок.

Comment: в ангуляре новичок, как проверить, что возвращает $location.path() ?

Comment: _как проверить, что возвращает $location.path()_ - например вывести во view: `{{$location.path()}}`

Comment: {{$location.path()}} - ничего не выводит :( пробовал {{1+1}} выдает 2.

Comment: о! ну конечно :-) а ты его в scope добавлял?:)

Comment: Сделал вот так:  angular.module('lostfound.pathlocation', []).controller('locationPath', function ($scope) {
        $scope.lpath = $location.path();
    });

Comment: angular.module('lostfound', ['lostfound.pathlocation']); и ставил через контроллер <div ng-controller="locationPath">{{lpath}}</div> - все равно, что то не так делаю((

Comment: уже мозг ламается в вопросе, что не так...

Comment: не, так не пойдет. Сделай [mcve] кода который у тебя есть, и добавь в вопрос

Comment: добавил короткий код

Comment: да, тут все правильно - у тебя действительно _path_ - пустая строка в этом случае

Comment: тогда почему же оно не срабатывает в условии? и ломает ввесь код что ниже?

Comment: не, не, не. В вопросе код абсолютно рабочий: значение пункции - пустая строка, ты и выводишь пустую строку - все ок. Исправь пример так, чтобы он воспроизводил твою ошибку. Ты пользуешься какими-нибудь роутерами?

Comment: Да, использу - angular-route, код показать?

Comment: ага, вот и добавляй конкретный пример с ним

Comment: Добавил полностью код с ангуляром. Рутинг все работает отлично, дату через контроллер добавляю, тоже все ок, как только подключаю через контроллер locationPath все ломается.